# "Reading from public effective user settings" in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I'm getting the following messages when launching my app:

```
2016-10-12 14:47:23.705002 Discovery[377:147958] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-10-12 14:47:23.712212 Discovery[377:147958] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Is "system group container" related to App Groups? I do share data between apps using an App Group and was wondering if this caused this message to be displayed?

I set the data in one app like this:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.myApp")
userDefaults!.setObject("user12345", forKey: "userId")
userDefaults!.synchronize()
```

And I retrieve it in another app using something like this:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.myApp")
if let testUserId = userDefaults?.objectForKey("userId") as? String {
  print("User Id: \(testUserId)")
}
```

Did something change in iOS 10 that would cause any problems or cause these messages to show up?

Comment: What errors? There are no errors in your question, just some annoying debug messages shown in iOS 10.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982683/mc-system-group-container-and-mc-reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-err?s=1|2.5517

Comment: True. I'll edit my question to reflect that. I guess the question is why are these messages showing up as I'm trying to figure out why my apps aren't sharing the data correctly.

Comment: As you can see from [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Reading+from+public+effective+user+settings), you are not the only one seeing this message.

Comment: Right, but I don't see any answers explaining what the messages are for?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Not yet. Most of the ideas I've found says this error seems to be related to Privacy Descriptions in one of the plist files (like Privacy - Camera Usage Description). For kicks I went to that plist and tried setting all 20 of the Privacy descriptions with a test string and that did not fix the warning. I'm not sure these warnings are even related to App Groups at this point but would still like to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 94):

This is a bug (now we're finding out it might be a permanent message) and it seems that this message appears primarily when clicking on a Text Field or Text View or other similar NSObject.

This is only a log message and not a compile error message as signified by the date and time preceding the message. Therefore if your code is not working it is not a result of this console message.

If you run on a device the message will be `[MC] Reading from public effective user settings`. If you run on the sim the message will be `[MC] Reading from private effective user settings`.

Comment: Thanks tymac.  I am seeing this message on a device when running Xcode 8.1.  Also, as you described, this message is showing up when I tap a ```UISearchbar's UITextField```.  Also, as you described, I cannot see anything in my project that is affected by this message or the triggering of this event.

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy your day.

Comment: Was banging my head with this thinking there was something wrong with my code. tymac is correct. This is only a bug/log message and cannot actually be fixed until we get out of beta. This is the correct answer with 10 votes yet it is not marked as the correct answer? Weird.

Comment: It seems out of beta, the issue still remains. Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: same with me. the issue still present XCode 8.3.2

Comment: Looks like we need a radar

Comment: In Xcode 8.3.2, I get this when I tap on a UITextField.  The iPhone keyboard fails to appear, so I assume that the debug message is indicative of something not working and not just a spurious message.

Comment: It’s possible it’s one of the newer included console messages but either way it’s just a log message and not a compile error.

Comment: I'm getting the same log message from the simulator on XCode 9.3.

Comment: Still appears in Xcode 10.2.1 when I tap on an InputField - it doesn't matter if the keyboard is shown afterwards or if it's disabled (with ⌘K).

Answer (score 29):

- Go to `Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`
- In the `Environment Variables`, add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` as name and `disable` as value.

[image: screenshot]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Happy coding.. @fmz

Comment: This was not helpful, it just turned off all the logging in the console.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why this is not the answer for this question?

Comment: not an ideal solution, mutes all system console warnings... constraint warnings can be very useful...

Answer (score 6):

Xcode seems to full of these confusing and misleading warnings. this warning appears when ever I enter text in a UITextField, at first I thought there is something wrong with my codes.

Comment: Xcode is absolutely full of weird quirks and bugs. There's always a new one you haven't seen, but they're few and far between that you end up forgetting the solutions which makes you waste even more time... Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Is your next output in console like this: `[access] <private>`. I've had your warnings, I was missing permission for camera usage in my plist file `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`. You need privacy description in plist for which privacy you are using: `Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone, Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider`

Comment: Yeah, I tried to set all of those and it did not get rid of the warning. I also did not have [access] <private> after my warning message so maybe I just have a different problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when touching a Bar button that showed an alert, which in turn has a TextField. Any way I solved this matter using the proposal commented in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476012/error-message-mc-reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-mc-system-g). It works at least for me!
regards!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue in an iPhone5 emulator (on the device everything was ok) that stucked my Ionic app after touch a TextInput, and then I changed the emulator to another one, like iPhone6, or iPhone8, and everything worked again.