# iOS System group error message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The following message get printed the first time the keyboard is shown, at every app launch. This has shown up ever since iOS 10 came out.

```
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Other people with the same results claim this to be linked to privacy settings, for camera and photo access. Can't really figure out what is going on here on my own, would be great if anyone knows what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not having any issues with your app, I would disregard this. I've noticed a bunch of new logging messages in Xcode 8 when running on the simulator that seem totally inconsequential.

See [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64237) on Apple Dev forum, the Apple Staff member doesn't indicate that it's a problem.

More info here: ["Reading from public effective user settings" in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024316/reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-in-ios-10)

Comment: Ok good to know, though i think its a poor choice by apple to allow these to be logged, without giving proper documentation on what they mean. I will mark this as correct as long as anybody else has a better answer with more detail.

Comment: Agreed. Let's hope they fix this in an upcoming Xcode release