# Reading from private effective user settings warning when simulator opening

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

When I click on textField to open simulator keyboard in the Xcode this wraning show up:

```
2017-01-01 17:19:38.668544 FirebaseChat[12334:2921090] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79C88538-E4D6-4CEF-8B20-8D514CF453A8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-01-01 17:19:38.669484 FirebaseChat[12334:2921090] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

I use xcode 8 and swift 3.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check [How to remove strange logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

Comment: Duplicate on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024316/reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-in-ios-10

Comment: Not a duplicate, since here it is about private effective settings and not public.

Comment: I have the same issue when clicking uitextfiled by a swift project. But it will be fine if you run on a real device. It seems a simulator bug... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024316/reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-in-ios-10

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the beta and it seems that this message appears primarily when clicking on a Text Field or Text View or other similar NSObject.

This is only a log message and not a compile error message as signified by the date and time preceding the message. Therefore if your code is not working it is not a result of this console message.

If you run on a device the message will be [MC] Reading from public effective user settings. If you run on the sim the message will be [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

> > There for , if xcode build successed then You don't care