# Reading from private effective user settings. No working answer

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I try to take the input from a text field, I get this error. Could anyone please help?

```
2017-05-08 17:45:04.962124 MyPhotos[32987:246251] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/local/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05F02AB6-BDEA-43EA-9E7E-D547D3A0CC1A/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-08 17:45:04.962486 MyPhotos[32987:246251] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

Code:

```
class AddPhotoController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoTags: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoURL: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoPreview: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func savePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        let title: String = photoTitle.text!
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run the code and try to get the value it always return nil and the application is crashed after that.

Comment: I don't think the above is the actual cause of your error. I'm seeing the "Reading from private effective user settings" from time to time as well (and no crashes :)) Have a look here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40458288/4063602, or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41416048/4063602 Seems like a bug in Xcode. So...could you show us some of your code so we can help you determine what causes the crash?

Comment: Yes i have. but lets say i have a button and i want to get the value of the textfield when i press it 
@IBAction func savePhoto(sender: AnyObject)
 {
         let title: String = photoTitle.text!
} 
This always return nil and the application it stuck at this point. i did try to check with a break point but i always return nil

Comment: please have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> lets say i have a button and i want to get the value of the textfield when i press it

If for some reason you are not able to read the value from `photoTitle` then your app will crash in this line:

`let title: String = photoTitle.text!`

Here you are trying to force the value of `photoTitle.text` into a `String` regardless of it being nil or not, and Swift doesn't like that :)

So, a first guard of defence could be to check whether the value actually is `nil` before you use it, and only if it isn't nil, then you use it. Something like:

```
@IBAction func savePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if photoTitle.text != nil {
        let title = photoTitle.text!
    }
}
```

Now you know that the value of `title` is not nil, and can use it safely.

Next question...why is it nil in the first place? That seems to be a problem with your `@IBOutlet`. It seems that the `photoTitle` var is not properly connected to the `UITextField` in your storyboard. Can you verify that your `UITextField` in Interface Builder is properly connected to you `photoTitle` variable?

Hope this helps you.