# Reading from private effective user settings When UISearchbar Clicked

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, ios10, xcode8

I'm using `XCode 8.1` and language objective c . i use `SearchBar` on `NavigationBar` .
When I open to `SearchBar` and click for writing something in `SearchBar` ,warning appears in `XCode` console.

How we resolved this. 
Plz help.

I added uisearchbar this way in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar * searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    searchBar.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView=searchBar;
}
```

**Warning ::::**

> PROJECT NAME [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/online/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SOME
>   NUMBERS/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   PROJECT NAME [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

Comment: please refer to the similar question as below:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024316/reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-in-ios-10/40458288

Answer (score 0):

Its a debug log message of iOS 10 just warning nothing else.

Ignore this as its not affect on any where like to upload on appstore or in approval.