# Error message : [MC] Reading from public effective user settings & [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

When I use the following code, I have error messages :

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:myQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSLog(@"response status code: %ld, error status : %@", (long)[httpResponse statusCode], error.description);

        if ((long)[httpResponse statusCode] >= 200 && (long)[httpResponse statusCode]< 400)
            {
               // do stuff
                [self requestFunction]; //Web Service
            }
}];
```

Error messages :

```
2017-02-27 01:13:30.088641 RENAULT[210:12313] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-27 01:13:30.090449 RENAULT[210:12313] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

The [self requestFunction] function launch a simple request :

```
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSString *url_string = [bytes stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[set_send_order stringByAppendingString: url_string]]];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:timeOut];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I precise that the connectionDidFinishLoading: is not called, but if I launch it directly without the sendAsynchronousRequest:, it works. 
So why the fact that I use sendAsynchronousRequest: function makes me appear the two error messages, and the miscalling of the connectionDidFinishLoading ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It occurs to me. The same logs in console when I use textField. Follow is my operation:

- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
- On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE in the value set disable

I solved it thanks to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65216?q=systemgroup%20container%20for#) discussion.

Comment: To be precise it just hides logging from console - it may be not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't solve the actual root of the problem. It only mutes the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If it occurs when the app tries to use keyboard for user to enter something.(like touch UITextField, enter password ...)
It may be the keyboard of Simulator of XCode has a problem.
Close the simulator and restart it can get a good result.