# How to connect custom cells to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an assignment where I should create a product list in view controller with table view and custom cells. I customized the cell and I'm getting a error while compiling.

```
class ElectronicsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var primeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
}


class ProductListViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!

    var electronicProducts = ["Swift DVD","Swift Manual","Beats EarPhones","IPad","I Watch"]
    var price = ["45","34","67","90","89"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate=self
        tableView.dataSource=self

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LabelCell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return electronicProducts.count
    }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell",for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ElectronicsTableViewCell

        let productName = electronicProducts [indexPath.row]
        cell.productNameLabel?.text = productName


        cell.buyLabel?.text = "Buy"

        cell.primeLabel?.text = "Prime Eligible"

        let productPrice = price [indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel?.text = productPrice


    return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("you selected cell \(indexPath.row)")
    }

}
```

The error is :
Reading from private effective user settings.
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10300f858) to 'assignment2.ElectronicsTableViewCell' (0x1013b3178).
(lldb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main issue is with the line:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LabelCell")
```

You need to register your custom class, so change UITableViewCell to ElectronicsTableViewCell.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have marked the class for the TableViewCell in the storyboard, is this by any chance a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024316/reading-from-public-effective-user-settings-in-ios-10)
Also avoid using force casts. Try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell",for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        if let labelCell = cell as? ElectronicsTableViewCell {
        let productName = electronicProducts [indexPath.row]
        labelCell.productNameLabel?.text = productName


        labelCell.buyLabel?.text = "Buy"

        labelCell.primeLabel?.text = "Prime Eligible"

        let productPrice = price [indexPath.row]
        labelCell.priceLabel?.text = productPrice
        return labelCell
        }
    return cell
    }
```